# EF Give following Id insted of my number

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I Get Table with Products from 1 to 10  Insted 1-4 and 7 to 12

```
db.product.Add(new Product() {Id=1 ,ProductType = 0,Active = false,});
db.product.Add(new Product() { Id = 2, ProductType = 0, Active = false, });
db.product.Add(new Product() { Id = 3, ProductType = 0, Active = false, });
db.product.Add(new Product() { Id = 4, ProductType = 0, Active = false, });
//  db.product.Add(new Product() { Id = 5, ProductType = 1, Active = false,SensorValue = 0});
//   db.product.Add(new Product() { Id = 6, ProductType = 2, Active = false, SensorValue = 0 });
db.product.Add(new Product() { Id = 7, ProductType = 3, Active = false, SensorValue = 0 });
db.product.Add(new Product() { Id = 8, ProductType = 4, Active = false, SensorValue = 0 });
db.product.Add(new Product() { Id = 9, ProductType = 5, Active = false, SensorValue = 0 });
db.product.Add(new Product() { Id = 10, ProductType = 6, Active = false});
db.product.Add(new Product() { Id = 11, ProductType = 7, Active = false });
db.product.Add(new Product() { Id = 12, ProductType = 8, Active = false });
```

Comment: Disable autoincrement for the Id column.

Comment: in your modelbuilder, add the line modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().Property(x=>x.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

Answer (score 1):

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]

public int Id { get; set; }
```